# Two identical Protractor tests in a row, second one fails

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I use Protractor 4.0.14 on an Angular 1.6.3 website.

I execute two identical tests. The first one will succeed but not the second one. Any idea ?

```
it('Should return a toast error on inferior amount', function () {
    $$('#purposeList input.amount').first().clear().sendKeys('4999');
    $$('button[type="submit"]').get(0).click();
    expect($('div.toast.toast-error').isPresent()).toBe(true);
    element.all(by.model('purpose.amount')).first().clear();
    $$('button.toast-close-button').each(function (item) {
        item.click();
    });
    expect($('button.toast-close-button').isPresent()).toBe(false);
});

it('Should return a toast error on inferior amount BIS', function () {
    $$('#purposeList input.amount').first().clear().sendKeys('4999');
    $$('button[type="submit"]').get(0).click();
    expect($('div.toast.toast-error').isPresent()).toBe(true);
    element.all(by.model('purpose.amount')).first().clear();
    $$('button.toast-close-button').each(function (item) {
        item.click();
    });
    expect($('button.toast-close-button').isPresent()).toBe(false);
});
```

The field is provided with a wrong amount so it throws a toast-error when I submit. When I do it manually, I get the toast-error. When doing it with protractor, only the first of the identical tests will pass. On the other, it looks like the toast is never launch or closed really quickly.

I tried sleeps, ignoreSynchronisation with browser wait. I tried to replace the $timeout by $interval in the service dealing with error toasts (although other $timeout could be present). It didn't change anything.

It is actually the first expect of the second it that is failing and there is no actual help from the error, it's just an expect at false instead of true :

```
Message:
Expected false to be true.
```

Edit :

So @LostJon, by handling every promises, do you mean like this :

```
it('Should return a toast error on inferior than authorized purpose amount on step 1 BIS', function () {
    $$('#purposeList input.amount').first().clear().then(function() {
        $$('#purposeList input.amount').first().sendKeys('4999').then(function () {
            $$('button[type="submit"]').get(0).click().then(function () {
                expect($('div.toast.toast-error').isPresent()).toBe(true);
                element.all(by.model('purpose.amount')).first().clear().then(function () {
                    $$('button.toast-close-button').each(function (item) {
                        item.click();
                    }).then(function () {
                        expect($('button.toast-close-button').isPresent()).toBe(false);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I tried it, same result.

Edit :

Apparently it was an ignoreSynchronization = true that was inside the wait instead of before. I didn't figure it out before because I also set browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000), so without synchronization, we were still waiting for the elements but it was not accurate.

Comment: can you add additional information on your question?  
like what happens after first click, sample html, where did it fail, what error was displayed in console, etc.

Comment: Can you identify first which of the two are failing? you can put a console.log to differentiate the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an ignoreSynchronization = true that was inside the wait instead of before. I didn't figure it out before because I also set browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000), so without synchronization, we were still waiting for the elements but it was not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

so, the below line returns a promise.

```
$$('button[type="submit"]').get(0).click();
```

Your code is running synchronously, when you should be handling the promise resolve from `click()`. In fact, your line that calls `clear()` also returns a promise, so that needs to be handled as well.

Comment: I added the modifications in the post to try but it didn't solve it, was it what you had in mind?

Comment: looks pretty good. only thing i would suggest is it seems like your `expect($('button.toast-close-button').isPresent()).toBe(false);` statement should be within the above promise resolve for `item.click()`.

Comment: I thought about it after, but it didn't change anything.
Are we supposed to resolve every promise like this to be really clean ?

Comment: @bwarff you need to resolve the promises if you are calling those operations sequentially. If you broke those up into multiple it statements (still resolving when necessary), it would make your code look cleaner. Also, you can utilize page objects to make your code more readable.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will do that to make it cleaner for the following, but sometimes it become harder to read with all the promises. And sometimes they are not necessary, except when you need the promise to get a value or a change. Currently, I only use them when I need something from them and didn't have problem with synchronization.

Comment: ^at least as far as you know of. A lot of times a test case can pass, giving a false positive, because of async issues.

Comment: the control flow handles promises and async, you don't need to resolve simple commands like `click()`

Comment: @Gunderson, im old school! Na, this is good info...gonna make cases a LOT cleaner in the future!